# What to do when Python requests.get gets a browser error from the website?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to read in a table from a website, but when I do this, I am getting a result from the website that says: "**It appears your browser may be outdated. For the best website experience, we recommend updating your browser**."

I am able to use requests.get on the Stats portion of this same PGA website without issue, but for some reason the way these historical results tables are displayed it is causing issues.  One interesting thing going on is the web site allows you to select different years for the displayed table, but doing that doesn't result in any difference to the address, so I suspect they are formatting it in a way that read_html won't work.  Any other suggestions?  Code below.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    farmers_url = 'https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/farmers-insurance-open/past-results.html'
    farmers = pd.read_html(requests.get(farmers_url).text, header=0)[0]
    farmers.head()
```

Comment: The message is because the website has checks that its lcient (your code) can run javascript, and those are indicating that it can’t so your code is like a very old browser that can’t run javascript The implication is they’re checking for scrapers, and/or they want to run javascript in the browser to read/display data rather than delivering full html pages. You’ll have to use a browser simulation like Selenium, or dig into the jvascript to find the requests it is making from the browser and see if you can replicate those using Python+requests.

Comment: The ;check’ miht simply be that the client hasn’t behaved like a normal browser for example a browser would always request images and javascript/css files specified in the page that’s just been delivered, but your code hasn’t done that. Or the check mught be something more subtle/complex, like the JS code makes an ajaz request, but your code hasn’t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a request to the following file for the content you want. This would otherwise be an additional request made by the browser from your start url. What you are currently getting is the actual content of a table at the requested url prior to any updates which would happen dynamically with a browser.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/farmers-insurance-open/past-results/jcr:content/mainParsys/pastresults.selectedYear.2021.004.html', headers=headers).text
pd.read_html(r)
```

If you want to do tidying to look like the actual webpage then something like the following transformations and cleaning:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/farmers-insurance-open/past-results/jcr:content/mainParsys/pastresults.selectedYear.2021.004.html', headers=headers).text
t = pd.read_html(r)[0]
t.reset_index()
t.columns = [':'.join([i[0], i[1]]) if 'ROUNDS' in i else i[0] for i in t.columns]
t.POS = t.POS.map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[-1])
round_columns = [i for i in t.columns if 'ROUNDS' in i]
t[round_columns] = t[round_columns].applymap(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
t.drop('TO PAR', inplace = True, axis = 1)
t.rename(columns={"TOTALSCORE": "TOTAL SCORE", "OFFICIALMONEY": "OFFICIAL MONEY", "FEDEXCUPPOINTS":"FEDEX CUP POINTS"}, inplace = True)
```

---

Detail:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response!  Some follow up questions
1) Using the new URL without the change of headers to Mozilla still works. What are you doing with the headers change you are making?  Why is that recommended?  I can't see a difference.
2) How did you find that URL?  When I go to the 2021 results and see that table, this URL is not changed in the address bar showing the year
3) There is one difference - in the displayed URL, the final POS is listed, but in your link, all 4 rounds are combined in one POS column.  Any way to get the resulting table to show like it does on the main site?

Comment: 1) Addition of header is to impersonate a browser 2) I found the url in the network tab of the browser (F12) when refreshing (F5) your original webpage 3) I would need to have a look

Comment: I have written some code to tidy the dataframe. Is that as desired?

Comment: Thank you!  You totally solved what I was looking for.  I'm going to dig into the code a bit to try to figure out what you did to help me learn this better (very much a beginner).  One thing from your previous answer I wasn't sure about after hitting F12 and looking at the Elements is I don't see that string anywhere. I'm guessing you pieced it together based on the Javascript?  Any tips for if I run into this sort of thing in the future how to find these "hidden" URLs?  Or is the answer to just learn some Javascript so I understand the structure better?

Comment: Go to my profile page and read through the 4 links against point 5 `Find xhr requests feeding dynamic content 1, 2, 3, 4`..... start with #4. I will add some notes to the code.

Comment: I have added some explanation for you.

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much for providing so much detail.  This really is helping me out learn my way around Python.

Comment: you are most welcome

Comment: I was able to follow your steps above, most helpful.  One thing that doesn't seem to be working is the column renaming in the last step.  The space doesn't appear between the words.  I even tried renaming it to something completely different (in case it was an issue with spaces appearing) and it also didn't work. It's formatted exactly as it should be according to Pandas help, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: Oops. I missed an argument: `t.rename(columns={"TOTALSCORE": "TOTAL SCORE", "OFFICIALMONEY": "OFFICIAL MONEY", "FEDEXCUPPOINTS":"FEDEX CUP POINTS"}, inplace = True)`

Comment: Thank you! All done with requests for this one, you have been a tremendous help!

Comment: the PGA website had a complete redesign and the "hidden" URLs that used to be there no longer seem to be and it has completely broken the tool I was using to pull this data (largely with your help here).  Are you able to discover a way to find the hidden URLs in the new site design that would allow you to search for historical winners of different seasons? Previously there was a SEASON and TOURN ID field that differentiated between them.  Does not appear that way any more.
https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/2023/fortinet-championship/R2023464/past-results

Comment: Hi, Please open a new question and include the steps to reproduce and what you have tried and where you are stuck and then others will also have a chance to have a look at the problem.

Comment: Thanks QHar.  I actually realized that was a better avenue than through the comments here and posted this new one below.  Looks like the new site uses GraphQL, hiding the content that used to be there.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75380332/how-to-scrape-data-from-new-2023-pga-tour-website-in-python/75387775#75387775