# How to scrape data from new (2023) PGA Tour website in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

The PGA tour updated their website (as of Feb 7, 2023) that completely broke the way I was scraping it for data.  It used to have a "hidden" URL that you could uncover by looking at the Network tab in Developer tools.  Then I could use that "hidden" URL with Requests in Python to pull the data tables.

For background on how it used to work, see the response from this previous post of mine: [What to do when Python requests.get gets a browser error from the website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70141129/what-to-do-when-python-requests-get-gets-a-browser-error-from-the-website).

Now it seems like all the data is obscured away from accessing it via a URL like before.  I'm hoping someone more fluent in web-scraping tricks can point me in the right direction to do what that previous link did:

1. For any tournament, be able to pull tournament history from any year/season. (Example from the new site: https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/2023/fortinet-championship/R2023464/past-results)
2. For any statistic, be able to pull stats from any year/season. (Example from the new site: https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/02674)

Initial try shows ability to pull the table off the current page (but not previous years) and some of the data that is pulled is not text, but rather formatting code.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

tournament_url = 'https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/2023/fortinet-championship/R2023464/past-results'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
t = pd.read_html(requests.get(tournament_url, headers=headers).text)[0]
t
```

**EDIT**: I see from a response below that this is using GraphQL.  I discovered that if you click on the `graphql` line in the Network tab and then look at the Payload tab, you'll see these variables: `{ "tournamentPastResultsId": "R2023464", "year": 2022 }`.

These seem to give the tournament ID and year in question so that in theory you can simply update these values in a query and pick any tournament, any year.  Integrating these into the scraping would mimic how it was done prior.  I'm not sure how to do that though.  I'll do some more research on Selenium.  Hopefully it is able to pass through these variables somehow.

**EDIT 2**:
The answer was given below for how to do this for the tournament data.  For Stats data (e.g. https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/02567), I was able to modify the code to get the appropriate table (see below).

Posted below for reference (thanks to @Jurakin!)

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import NaN
import requests

# in the requests header seems to be a constant token ('x-api-key') that is needed
X_API_KEY = "da2-gsrx5bibzbb4njvhl7t37wqyl4"

YEAR = 2022  # Stats Season
STAT_ID = "02567"  # Stat ID

# prepare the payload
payload = {
    "operationName": "StatDetails",
    "variables": {
        "tourCode": "R",
        "statId": STAT_ID,
        "year": YEAR,
        "eventQuery": None
    },
    "query": "query StatDetails($tourCode: TourCode!, $statId: String!, $year: Int, $eventQuery: StatDetailEventQuery) {\n  statDetails(\n    tourCode: $tourCode\n    statId: $statId\n    year: $year\n    eventQuery: $eventQuery\n  ) {\n    tourCode\n    year\n    displaySeason\n    statId\n    statType\n    tournamentPills {\n      tournamentId\n      displayName\n    }\n    yearPills {\n      year\n      displaySeason\n    }\n    statTitle\n    statDescription\n    tourAvg\n    lastProcessed\n    statHeaders\n    statCategories {\n      category\n      displayName\n      subCategories {\n        displayName\n        stats {\n          statId\n          statTitle\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    rows {\n      ... on StatDetailsPlayer {\n        __typename\n        playerId\n        playerName\n        country\n        countryFlag\n        rank\n        rankDiff\n        rankChangeTendency\n        stats {\n          statName\n          statValue\n          color\n        }\n      }\n      ... on StatDetailTourAvg {\n        __typename\n        displayName\n        value\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"  
  }

# post the request
page = requests.post("https://orchestrator.pgatour.com/graphql", json=payload, headers={"x-api-key": X_API_KEY})

# check for status code
page.raise_for_status()

# get the data
data = page.json()["data"]["statDetails"]["rows"]

# print(data)

# format to a table that is in the webpage
table = map(lambda item: {
    "rank": item["rank"],
    "player": item["playerName"],
    "average": item["stats"][0]["statValue"],
}, data)

# convert the dataframe
s = pd.DataFrame(table)

s
```

**EDIT 3 - FOLLOW UP QUESTION**:
The answer above for stats work for stats with 5 characters in the Stat ID.  But there are others with 3 characters (e.g. https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/156) that do grab the data correctly, but fail in the table mapping portion despite what I can tell are identical Response formats, so I am at a loss why this does not work and the other does.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import NaN
import requests

# in the requests header seems to be a constant token ('x-api-key') that is needed
X_API_KEY = "da2-gsrx5bibzbb4njvhl7t37wqyl4"

YEAR = 2022  # Stats Season
# STAT_ID = "02567"  # Stat ID SGOTT
STAT_ID = "156"  # Birdie Average - doesn't work for stats that only have three numbers and I can't figure out why

# prepare the payload
payload = {
    "operationName": "StatDetails",
    "variables": {
        "tourCode": "R",
        "statId": STAT_ID,
        "year": YEAR,
        "eventQuery": None
    },
    "query": "query StatDetails($tourCode: TourCode!, $statId: String!, $year: Int, $eventQuery: StatDetailEventQuery) {\n  statDetails(\n    tourCode: $tourCode\n    statId: $statId\n    year: $year\n    eventQuery: $eventQuery\n  ) {\n    tourCode\n    year\n    displaySeason\n    statId\n    statType\n    tournamentPills {\n      tournamentId\n      displayName\n    }\n    yearPills {\n      year\n      displaySeason\n    }\n    statTitle\n    statDescription\n    tourAvg\n    lastProcessed\n    statHeaders\n    statCategories {\n      category\n      displayName\n      subCategories {\n        displayName\n        stats {\n          statId\n          statTitle\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    rows {\n      ... on StatDetailsPlayer {\n        __typename\n        playerId\n        playerName\n        country\n        countryFlag\n        rank\n        rankDiff\n        rankChangeTendency\n        stats {\n          statName\n          statValue\n          color\n        }\n      }\n      ... on StatDetailTourAvg {\n        __typename\n        displayName\n        value\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}"  
  }

# post the request
page = requests.post("https://orchestrator.pgatour.com/graphql", json=payload, headers={"x-api-key": X_API_KEY})

# check for status code
page.raise_for_status()

# get the data
data = page.json()["data"]["statDetails"]["rows"]

print(data)

# format to a table that is in the webpage
table = map(lambda item: {
    "RANK": item["rank"],
    "PLAYER": item["playerName"],
    "AVERAGE": item["stats"][0]["statValue"],
}, data)

# convert the dataframe
s = pd.DataFrame(table)

s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in devtools, the page uses [`graphql`](https://graphql.org/). `graphql` is a bit complicated for me and would take a long time to deobfuscate and understand the code, so I used [`selenium4`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to run the javascript and build the table.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# load page
driver.get("https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/2023/fortinet-championship/R2023464/past-results")

# get table
table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.chakra-table")
assert table, "table not found"

# remove empty rows
driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].querySelectorAll("td.css-1au52ex").forEach((e) => e.parentElement.remove())""", table)

# get html of the table
table_html = table.get_attribute("outerHTML")

# quit selenium
driver.quit()

df = pd.read_html(table_html)[0]

print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
     Pos             Player  R1   R2   R3   R4 To Par  FedExCup Pts Official Money
0      1           Max Homa  -7   -5    E   -4    -16         500.0     $1,440,000
1      2      Danny Willett  -4   -8    E   -3    -15         300.0       $872,000
2      3  Taylor Montgomery  -4   -1    E   -8    -13         190.0       $552,000
3     T4       Justin Lower  -9   -1   -3   +1    -12         122.5       $360,000
4     T4      Byeong Hun An  -6   -4   -1   -1    -12         122.5       $360,000
..   ...                ...  ..  ...  ...  ...    ...           ...            ...
151  CUT         Doc Redman  +2   +6  NaN  NaN     +8           0.0             $0
152  CUT       Kyle Stanley  +6   +2  NaN  NaN     +8           0.0             $0
153  CUT         Jim Herman  -1  +10  NaN  NaN     +9           0.0             $0
154  CUT        Taylor Lowe  +9   +8  NaN  NaN    +17           0.0             $0
155  W/D   Brandon Matthews   -  NaN  NaN  NaN      E           0.0             $0

[156 rows x 9 columns]
```

## EDIT:

I created script that uses `graphql` api to fetch the data as you told me in the comments.

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy import NaN
import requests

# in the requests header seems to be a constant token
X_API_KEY = "da2-gsrx5bibzbb4njvhl7t37wqyl4"

YEAR = 2023
PAST_RESULTS_ID = "R2023464"

# prepare the payload
payload = {
    "operationName": "TournamentPastResults",
    "variables": {
        "tournamentPastResultsId": PAST_RESULTS_ID,
        "year": YEAR
    },
    "query": "query TournamentPastResults($tournamentPastResultsId: ID!, $year: Int) {\n  tournamentPastResults(id: $tournamentPastResultsId, year: $year) {\n    id\n    players {\n      id\n      position\n      player {\n        id\n        firstName\n        lastName\n        shortName\n        displayName\n        abbreviations\n        abbreviationsAccessibilityText\n        amateur\n        country\n        countryFlag\n        lineColor\n      }\n      rounds {\n        score\n        parRelativeScore\n      }\n      additionalData\n      total\n      parRelativeScore\n    }\n    rounds\n    additionalDataHeaders\n    availableSeasons {\n      year\n      displaySeason\n    }\n    winner {\n      id\n      firstName\n      lastName\n      totalStrokes\n      totalScore\n      countryFlag\n      countryName\n      purse\n      points\n    }\n  }\n}"
}

# post the request
page = requests.post("https://orchestrator.pgatour.com/graphql", json=payload, headers={"x-api-key": X_API_KEY})

# check for status code
page.raise_for_status()

# get the data
data = page.json()["data"]["tournamentPastResults"]["players"]

# format to a table that is in the webpage
table = map(lambda item: {
    "pos": item["position"],
    "player": item["player"]["displayName"],
    "r1": item["rounds"][0]["parRelativeScore"] if len(item["rounds"]) > 0 else NaN,
    "r2": item["rounds"][1]["parRelativeScore"] if len(item["rounds"]) > 1 else NaN,
    "r3": item["rounds"][2]["parRelativeScore"] if len(item["rounds"]) > 2 else NaN,
    "r4": item["rounds"][3]["parRelativeScore"] if len(item["rounds"]) > 3 else NaN,
    "to par": item["parRelativeScore"],
    "fedexcup pts": item["additionalData"][0],
    "official money": item["additionalData"][1],
}, data)

# convert the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(table)

print(df)
```

## EDIT 3:

The code raises a `KeyError: 'rank'` error because the item does not have a rank attribute. I used the following code to get an invalid item:

```
# get the data
data = page.json()["data"]["statDetails"]["rows"]

for item in data:
    if "rank" not in item:
        print(item)

# Outputs:
# {"__typename": "StatDetailTourAvg", "displayName": "Tour Average", "value": "3.64"},
```

As you can see, his `__typename` is different from all the others. I found two solutions:

#### Solution A

Filter out items that's `__typename` is not equal to `StatDetailsPlayer`:

```py
...

# get the data
data = page.json()["data"]["statDetails"]["rows"]

# print(data)

# filter out items, thats __typename is not "StatDetailsPlayer" like
# {"__typename": "StatDetailTourAvg", "displayName": "Tour Average", "value": "3.64"}
data = filter(lambda item: item.get("__typename", NaN) == "StatDetailsPlayer", data)

# format to a table that is in the webpage
table = map(lambda item: {
    "RANK": item["rank"],
    "PLAYER": item["playerName"],
    "AVERAGE": item["stats"][0]["statValue"],
}, data)


# convert the dataframe
s = pd.DataFrame(table)

print(s)
```

#### Solution B

Attempts to retrieve attributes from the object if possible, otherwise returns `NaN`.

```
...

def get(obj: object, keys: list, default=NaN):
    """
    obj = {"a": {"b": {"c": [0, 1, 2, 3]}}}
    keys = ["a", "b", "c", 0]
    # returns 0
    out = get(obj, keys, default=NaN)
    # return NaN
    out = get(obj, ["a", "c"])
    """
    for key in keys:
        try:
            obj = obj[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default
    return obj

# format to a table that is in the webpage
table = map(lambda item: {
    "RANK": item.get("rank", NaN), # NaN is default (using buit-in function)
    "PLAYER": item.get("playerName", NaN),
    "AVERAGE": get(item, ["stats", 0, "statValue"] default=NaN), # my function (built-in function does not support multiple keys)
}, data)

# convert the dataframe
s = pd.DataFrame(table)

print(s)
```

#### Difference

Solution A does not contain invalid row, Solution B does.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of Selenium and it seems like mimicking the web browser might be the best way to capture this data.  Question for you though, can it dynamically pass through variables? I edited my post to ad this info above, but there are two variables that dictate the tournament and year `{
  "tournamentPastResultsId": "R2023464",
  "year": 2022
}`.  Ideally these would be integrated into the scraping script so that I can change those out with an f string as tournaments/years change.

Comment: @RyanMiller See my edit. I created script that uses `graphql` api to fetch the data as you told me in the comments

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to try to dig into what you did so I fully understand it.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am going through your code line by line to make sure I understood how you are doing things.  I'm stuck on one area.  When you define the data:
`data = page.json()["data"]["tournamentPastResults"]["players"]`
how did you know what to put here? I thought you were pulling specific lists from the query that you then wanted to use for the table.  But in trying to recreate this for the stats (https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/02567) I tried to use this as table data using the same logic from the new query and it's not working:
`data = page.json()["data"]["statDetails"]["rows"]`

Comment: @RyanMiller I found out that the site is getting data from the response of request that you specified in the question. I opened dev tools network tab and it was in the response

Comment: I have a follow up question that I posted in my original post (EDIT #3).  I was able to use your logic to scrape stats pages as well, but it seems to break when the Stat ID is 3 vs. 5 characters. However, the query and response seems exactly the same between the two stat types, so I'm not sure why it is throwing an error.  Would you mind looking at my code and seeing where it is having an issue between the two stat types?

Comment: Thank you for walking me through the troubleshooting steps.  I learn a lot through these activities.  I was not aware that one of the items in the data set was the reason for the error or how to narrow down what that might be.  Your solution A is very simple and gets the list of player names as desired.  I have learned a lot of new Python concepts through your explanations, thank you for taking the time to do this.