# Unable to scrape tournament-speciifc data from new (2023) PGA Tour website in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I following on this item [  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75380332/how-to-scrape-data-from-new-2023-pga-tour-website-in-python ] and successfully scraped data from stats style pages (e.g. https://www.pgatour.com/stats/detail/02675 ). Thanks @user:14934246  @ryan-miller

I've been trying to follow the same pattern for this **tournament-specific** URL below. Where my goal is to be able to scrape the player name and player ID for each player in the field

I feel like I'm close, but I can't quite figure out why the JSON request isn't coming back successfully.

URL: https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/2023/mexico-open-at-vidanta/R2023540

I followed the same steps:

1. In Chrome, navigate to URL above hit Ctrl+Shift+I to reveal "Network" tab in developer tools
2. Navigate to the graphql entry. Click on Payload tab and take note of: the query syntax and the variables
3. Adjusted the code below to amend details for FIELD_ID, payload & query.

*Any ideas where I've gone wrong?*

This is the code I ran:

```
`X_API_KEY = "da2-gsrx5bibzbb4njvhl7t37wqyl4"

FIELD_ID = "R2023540"  # ID for the field in a specific tournament

# prepare the payload
payload = {
    "operationName": "Field",
    "variables": {
        "fieldId": FIELD_ID, "includeWithdrawn": 0, "changesOnly": "false"},
    "query": "query Field($fieldId: ID!, $includeWithdrawn: Boolean, $changesOnly: Boolean) { fieldid: $fieldId includeWithdrawn: $includeWithdrawn changesOnly: $changesOnly) { tournamentName id    lastUpdated    message    players {      ...FieldPlayer      teammate {        id        alphaSort        firstName        lastName        shortName        displayName        amateur        favorite        country        countryFlag        headshot        qualifier        alternate        withdrawn        status        owgr        rankingPoints      }    }    

    
    page = requests.post("https://orchestrator.pgatour.com/graphql", json=payload, headers={"x-api-key": X_API_KEY})
    page.raise_for_status()
    data_field = page.json()["data"]["field"]["players"]`

This is the error I noted:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20940/167507943.py in <module>
     16 page.raise_for_status()
     17 # get the data
---> 18 data_field = page.json()["data"]["field"]["players"]
     19 print(data_field)

KeyError: 'data'
```

Answer (score 1):

I very much appreciate the insight Le_Me - thank you!

I have clicked "up" to show appreciation, but I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, however my positive feedback has been recorded.

The tweaks you suggested were certainly valid, as clearly I'd manually introduced some syntax error.

After some playing around I figured out how to get it working successfully.

I went back to basics and found a more accurate way of pulling the query from Chrome. Steps below.

1. In Chrome, navigate to URL above hit Ctrl+Shift+I to reveal "Network" tab in developer tools
2. Navigate to the graphql entry. Click on Payload tab
3. Find the graphql entry, right click & select **"Copy as JSON literal"** (Do NOT choose "Copy value", as I had done previously, as you'll tie yourself in knots trying to convert it to one line of code without introducing a syntax error)

Answer (score 0):

After reading over the code I believe the cause may be some syntax errors.

their is a missing "(" between field and id inside the query. You are missing a comma between the different variables inside the query, and you are missing 2 "}" at the end of the query to complete the pairs. This throws the below error which is why your code cannot find the "data"

```
content: b'{\n  "errors" : [ {\n    "message" : "Unable to parse GraphQL query.",\n    "errorType" : "MalformedHttpRequestException"\n  } ]\n}'
```

Here is the query with corrected syntax

```
payload = {
    "operationName": "Field",
    "variables": {
    "fieldId": FIELD_ID, "includeWithdrawn": 0, "changesOnly": "false"},
    "query": "query Field($fieldId: ID!, $includeWithdrawn: Boolean,             
              $changesOnly: Boolean) "
         "{ field(id: $fieldId, includeWithdrawn: $includeWithdrawn, 
              changesOnly: $changesOnly) "
         "{ tournamentName id lastUpdated message players { ...FieldPlayer 
              teammate "
         "{ id alphaSort firstName lastName shortName displayName amateur 
          favorite country countryFlag "
         "headshot qualifier alternate withdrawn status owgr rankingPoints } } } }"
```

}